# libgeos_c.so undefined symbol: GEOSisClosed

Tags: apache, wsgi, ckan

I was trying to set up the CKAN with couple extensions. The main extension is spatial ( https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-spatial)> During the tests server returns code 500.

The log is:

> AttributeError: /usr/lib/libgeos_c.so.1: undefined symbol: GEOSisClosed

I couldn't find similar issue / attribute. Does anyone faced similar error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be an issue with the recent versions of Shapely, according to this: https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/176

It looks like this became a problem for installers during September, because the ckanext-spatial's pip-requirements.txt will get you the latest version "Shapely>=1.2.13". It sounds like the latest version is fixed though, so try that - 1.4.3 (released 1st Oct 2014) or failing that, an earlier one (e.g. 1.3.3).

```
(pyenv) $ pip install 'Shapely>=1.4.3'
```

Comment: And eight months later you save my day. Newer versions didn't work either, I had tu run: `pip install 'Shapely==1.4.3'`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you installed the GEOS package

```
sudo apt-get install libgeos-c1
```

If still no luck try installing the development libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev
```

Comment: both are there, still no luck

Answer (score 0):

I have shapely 1.5.9 installed on Ubuntu and I was receiving a similar error...

```
AttributeError: /usr/lib/libgeos_c.so.1: undefined symbol: GEOSCovers
```

I had to revert to a previous version of Shapely to get this to work. Try this command.

```
sudo pip install 'Shapely==1.4.3'
```